# ExtJS 6 Make ViewController talk to each other

Tags: events, extjs, viewcontroller, extjs6

I have two ViewController.
The first one fires an event if I select an item in a treepanel :

```
// treeController

    onItemSelection: function(treeview, record) {
        var me = this,
            controller = me.getView().getController();

        ...

        controller.fireEvent('myEvent', record);
    }
```

The second one is listening to this event.
The controller is responsible for uploading a file to a specified url. 
This url is set by the onMyEvent-function.

```
// uploadController

    ...    
    listen: {
            controller: {
                '*': {
                    myEvent: 'onMyEvent'
                }
            }
        },

        defaultUrl: 'foo/bar/{id}',
        currentUrl: null,

        onMyEvent: function(record) {
            var me = this;
            me.currentUrl = me.defaultUrl.replace('{id}', record.getId());
        },

        onUploadClick: function (form) {
            var me = this;
            if (form.isValid()) {
                form.submit({
                    url: me.currentUrl,
                    ...
                });
            }
        },
    ...
```

What I want to achieve: 
I select an item in the treepanel
-> the event is fired, the onMyEvent-function has been executed.

I click on the button to open the uploadView (the view which is connected to the controller). After that I'll click on the fileupload-button, select a file and click on the uploadbutton. 
After the uploadbutton has been pressed, the controller should call the onUploadClick-function and use the previous placed url (currentUrl) for the upload.

The problems I'm facing:

1. Selecting an item in the treepanel fires the event, but the uploadController is not executing the onMyEvent-function.
   When I open the uploadView first and select afterwards a node in the panel, the onMyEvent-function is executed.
2. When I use the second approach and try to upload the file, I get an error which tells me I haven't specifed the url (its null).

How can I accomplish the process without using the mentioned workaround for 1.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I agree with @JuanMendes that it will be better to fire the events from View instead of Controller. Moreover, I was wondering why do you need another event to set the Url when it could be just a function? If you're going to execute it from multiple sources, then it's acceptable. However, in that case I'd define it in the parent ViewController.

Comment: My suggestion, don't fire events from controllers. Views fire events and controllers listen to events.

Comment: If these two components have to work together why don't you put them on a new view with its own viewController?

Comment: Seems to me that you have a problem in your architecture. I'm not sure about controllers should not fire events, I think controllers can perfectly fire events for other (child)controllers to listen to, but in your case I think you should redesign your app..

Comment: I found this kind of approach on different websites (and blogs / articles of sencha developer) and the sencha documentation. I would really appreciate if you could give me a valuable answer instead of telling me how it should not be done (because this isn't helping so far).

Answer (score 1):

Your event `myEvent` is in `UploadController`. However, `controller.fireEvent('myEvent', record);` would try to find and fire it in `TreeController`.

Root cause of this issue is that `controller = me.getView().getController();` is going to give you back `this`/instance of `TreeController`. When you do `me.getView()`,it gives you `TreeView` and `me.getView().getController()` is going to give you back an instance of `TreeController` and you need an instance of `UploadController` cause `myEvent` is an event of `UploadController`.

The reason you're able to fire the event when you open `UploadView` first is cause you're already in `UploadController`.

Hope that helps!